# Where is the source of firefox.desktop to send a pull request?

Tags: firefox, launchpad, source-code

There is a small bug in `/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop`:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1615549
and I'd like to fix it and send a patch but I can't find a repository where the source of it is located. Can anyone point me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in multiple bazaar repositories based on the release. For example:

- 17.04: https://code.launchpad.net/~mozillateam/firefox/firefox.zesty
- 14.04: https://code.launchpad.net/~mozillateam/firefox/firefox.trusty

The file you're interested is in `debian/firefox.desktop.in` (example: [17.04](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mozillateam/firefox/firefox.zesty/view/head:/debian/firefox.desktop.in)).

How did I find out?

1. The [Firefox code page in LP](https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox) doesn't list any active repos.
2. Recent builds were all by [Chris Coulson](https://launchpad.net/~chrisccoulson), and
3. [The list of repos to which he's registered](https://code.launchpad.net/~chrisccoulson/+branches?field.category=REGISTERED&field.category-empty-marker=1&field.lifecycle=CURRENT&field.lifecycle-empty-marker=1&field.sort_by=most%20recently%20changed%20first&field.sort_by-empty-marker=1) includes these.